# Comparison of bivariate generating functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions

Suppose we have two bivariate ordinary generating functions describing two integer sequences which have indicies $a,b$ and $c, d$ respectively.

Is there a straightforward way to determine, from operating on the generating functions, the values of $a, b, c ,d$ for which the two bivariate integer sequences obtain the same value?